# android apk showing standard icon when istall -how fix it?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, icons, apk

I create android apk (with Flutter). I use this command:

```
flutter build apk
```

next step I will install the received package. during the installation process, I will use the "standard" icon, which is different from the application icon.

[image]

this is an example of display in "File manager", my apks is "standard icon" (not correct). facebook apk - application icon (correct)

[image]

when the application is installed - the appl icon is displayed for launch (correct icon).
this is part of my manifest:

```
     <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

how do I fix this? so that the application icon is displayed during the installation process?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flutter_launcher_icons` package to make your app icon however you want. The best part is it sets both android and iOS icon at the same therefore you don't have to worry about that.

Here's the link for it: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons

Comment: I am used flutter_launcher_icons, but I have this issue

Comment: Do you get the icon appropriate while installing other apps?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the Facebook apk - its icon is displayed

Comment: Could you please share your pubspec.yaml ?